# Many 'this of that' - why does usage invert for dogs?

Tags: grammatical-number

The question about [**'species of moth'**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/428567/is-it-species-of-plural-or-species-of-singular) intrigued me because the subject of 'many this of that' reveals something about how we conceptualise unknown quantities. A countable thing (like the number of moths in the whole world) can be regarded as an uncountable entity (since I cannot possibly know the number) and therefore can be regarded, conceptually, as 'mothness'.

In which case I might express 'species of moth' rather than 'moths'.

---

So I looked at a number of Ngrams and was surprised at the result.

- 75% of people favour [**'many kinds of food'**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=many+types+of+food%2C+many+types+of+foods&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmany%20types%20of%20food%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmany%20types%20of%20foods%3B%2Cc0) over 'many kinds of foods'.
- 75% of people favour [**'many kinds of wine'**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=many+kinds+of+wine%2C+many+kinds+of+wines&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmany%20kinds%20of%20wine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmany%20kinds%20of%20wines%3B%2Cc0) over '... wines'.
- 75% of people favour [**'many makes of car'**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=many+makes+of+car%2C+many+makes+of+cars&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmany%20makes%20of%20car%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmany%20makes%20of%20cars%3B%2Cc0) over '... cars'.

But the order reverses for dogs :

- 75% of people favour [**'many breeds of dogs'**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=many+breeds+of+dog%2C+many+breeds+of+dogs&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmany%20breeds%20of%20dog%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmany%20breeds%20of%20dogs%3B%2Cc0) over '... dog'.

I am interested in how we manage global concepts, whether fluid (wine) or disparate (food) or quantised (cars/dogs).

Can anyone suggest why there should be this reversal regarding dogs ?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd like to have to come up with an accurate figure for the number of dogs or cars in the world either.

Comment: Interesting observation. The case of _wine_ and _food_ is different, because those are often used uncountably. But _car_ vs. _dog_ is hard to account for.

Comment: @Colin: I can't see any real consistency here. According to Google Books, plural [two kinds of **cars**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22two+kinds+of+cars%22) is almost twice as common as singular [two kinds of **car**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22two+kinds+of+car%22) (the *opposite* preference to that implied by OP's ***many makes*** example). On the other hand, I'm not surprised to see that singular *two kinds of **wine*** is seven times as common as plural *two kinds of **wines***, which reflects OP's examples for that particular noun.

Comment: I can't answer, as I'm in the 25% who would say "many breeds of dog."

Comment: [These Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=many+types+of+horses%2Cmany+types+of+horse&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmany%20types%20of%20horses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmany%20types%20of%20horse%3B%2Cc0) seem to show that it's pretty idiosyncratic. Using 'breeds/kinds of horse/s' reveals that in these cases, the plural form is favoured.

Comment: Yep, you can get a lot of false positives with the singular just being the start of a compound (plural) noun. [More Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+horses+are%2Cof+horse+are%2Cof+car+are%2Cof+cars+are%2C+of+dogs+are%2C+of+dog+are&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20horses%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20horse%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20car%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20cars%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20dogs%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20dog%20are%3B%2Cc0)