# Why did "species" take over the singular?

Tags: nouns, language-evolution, irregular-plurals

As far as I know, it is very rare to have a noun in English that is both singular and plural and ends with "s". But "species" is such a noun, and I was surprised to learn that it actually *became* that way after *originally* having "specie" as the singular ([from Latin](https://grammarist.com/usage/species)).

Why did this happen?

I saw [this other English SE post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/428567) but it did not explain what drove the shift, and it seems counter-intuitive that people actually stopped using "specie" for the singular since switching to "species" would go against the default rule that adding "s" denotes the plural.

Comment: *Species* is like *series*. It's their declension. The version without the s is ablative case: *in serie*.

Comment: ***Biceps*** (and tri- and quadri-) is a singular / plural word as well. Often used as only plural, though medically there is no singular *bicep*.

Comment: _Specie_ is still in use...it refers to money in the form of coin.

Comment: @Cascabel: I know that, please read the links I provided. It doesn't answer my question at all of why for animal species the plural took over the singular.

Comment: @tchrist: If you disagree with the link I provided, which explicitly states that originally "specie" was used for the singular of "species", where is your evidence?

Comment: I suspect that in this case it's _not_ survival of the fittest. Which leaves Divine intervention, human idiosyncrasy, and complete fluke.

Comment: @user21820 I'm still trying to find licensing of the non-count sense I'm sure I've seen. May need OED. 'Accidence' is worse, and 'coincidence' inappropriate.

Comment: @tchrist It is worth adding that all fifth declension nouns in Latin have the same endings in the plural (-es).  Possibly also it is worth saying that adding a plural ending is just too horrible for the speaker to pronounce and for listener to hear.

Comment: @Tuffy Indeed the grating † *specieses* is a form long dead.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I think tchrist has shown that the link I provided is wrong, so the weirdness has gone away now. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It didn’t “take over”. That premise is incorrect. *Species* has ***always*** been singular, and the old plural *specieses* is obsolete.

## Obsolete or erroneous *specie*

The form *specie* to mean what we now mean by *species*—that is, “kind”—the OED says is:

> #### Now *Obsolete* except as erroneous singular of *species n.* 10.

It provides such citations for that sense now held to be erroneous in current use as these:

> - **1711** *London Gaz.* No. 4874/4
>    To prepare a List of each respective Specie [of bills] which they intend to Subscribe.
> - **1738** G. Smith *Curious Relations* II. 558
>    Such Men who are Plagues to their own Specie.
> - **1747** *Fool* (1748) II. 141
>    Our Hero made Divinities, though of a peculiar Specie.
> - **1800** C. Sturt in *Naval Chron*. 4 396
>    A very large specie of gull.
> - **1810**   *Splendid Follies* III. 193 
>     Such is the specie of game after which Nettletop is now in search.
> - **1858**   in J. R. Bartlett *Dict. Americanisms* (1859) 432 
>     The size of the trap,..and the nature of the bait, depends upon the specie of the animal hunted for.
> - **1980** *Daily Tel.* 22 Jan. 11/2
>    Castrated rats and other animals live longer than normal creatures of the specie.
> - **1980** *Pan Am Clipper* Oct. 48/1
>    Is he [*sc*. man] descended directly from apes, or is he a specie that evolved from an entirely new..branch of the primate tree?

It seems clear to me that the old ones are obsolete and the newer ones erroneous, but I don’t know how to assign which of the *obsolete* vs. *erroneous* label to citations more recent than 1800 but less recent than 1980. If you made me guess, I would guess obsolescence occurred sometime during the 19th century. I don’t know how to determine that though.

## *Species* has always been singular

Indeed, *species* has ***always*** been singular, just as it normally is
today.  The obsolete versions cited above were always a rare use even in
the 1700s.  The OED gives this for its etymology:

> Latin *speciēs* (ablative singular *speciē* **specie** *n.*) appearance,
> form, kind, etc., < *specĕre* to look, behold; hence also German *species*,
> *spezies*.  Within the Romanic languages the word is represented by Italian
> *specie*, *spezie*, Spanish *especie* (and *especia*), Portuguese *especie*
> (and *especia*), Old French *espece* (French *espèce*) and *espice* (French
> *épice*): see **spece** *n.*  and **spice** *n.*

Indeed all the [Latin fifth-declension nouns](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Latin_fifth_declension) worked this way. See also *series* versus *in serie*.

And here are some of its earlier citations:

> - **1551** T. Wilson *Rule of Reason* sig. Bvj
>    Species is a common word that is spoken of many whiche differ only in number, as manne is spoken of Socrates,..and of euery proper name belonging to any man. As Socrates is a man.
> - **1559** P. Morwyng tr. C. Gesner *Treasure of Euonymus* 400
>    An other very good wine with the same species, but in other weight.
> - **1561** T. Hoby tr. B. Castiglione *Courtyer* iii. sig. Cc.iii
>    Both the one and the other is conteined vnder the Species of *Homo*.
> - **1567** J. Jewel Def. *Apol. Churche Eng.* iii. v. 343
>    What adoo was made in daily disputations..aboute Genus and Species, and the reste of the Vniuersals.
> - **1608** E. Topsell *Hist. Serpents* 126
>    Some haue taken the word Crocodilus for the Genus, and the seuerall Species, they distinguish into the Crocodile of the Earth, and the water.
> - **1617** F. Moryson *Itinerary* i. 275
>    With covenant to deliver him by his Factor the same [coins], both in the Species or Kind, and in the number.
> - **a1618** W. Raleigh *Prerog. Parl.* 58
>    If all be content to pay upon moderation and change of the Species.
> - **1629** W. Prynne *Church of Englands Old Antithesis* 98
>    This kind of argument from euery indiuiduall to the speecies will not hold.
> - **1660** R. Coke *Justice Vindicated* ɪɪ. 26
>    If the Scriptures be true,..that since Adam..the species of Mankind was continued by generation.
> - **1660** tr. I. Barrow *Euclide's Elements* ᴠɪ. 119
>    The angles C and F are not of the same species or kind.
> - **1668**   Bp. J. Wilkins Ess. Real Char. ɪɪ. i. §3. 26   That common nature which is communicable to several Individuals, is called Species, Sort or special kind.
> - **1690** J. Locke *Ess. Humane Understanding* ɪɪɪ. vi. 211
>    The Individuals that are ranked into one Sort, called by one common Name, and so received as being of one Species.
> - **1730** P. Miller *Gardeners Dict.* at *Leontopetalon*
>    We have but one Species of this Plant in the English Gardens.
> - **1753** Chambers's *Cycl. Suppl.* at *Specific*
>    The *torpedo maculosa*, and *non maculosa*, seem to express two species different only in the spots.
> - **1843**   J. S. Mill *Syst. Logic* I. ɪ. vii. §3 
>     In this popular sense any two classes one of which includes the whole of the other and more may be called a genus and a species.

That shows that *species* has always been singular.

## Plural †*specieses* is long dead

During the 1600s–1800s the now-extinct form †*specieses* was sometimes used
for the corresponding plural, but today its plural is the same as its
singular has always been. Here are some of those *specieses* citations
for the plural:

> - **1644** K. Digby *Two Treat.* ɪ. xxxviii. 329
>    If there be aboundance of specieses of any one kind of obiect then strong in the imagination.
> - **1644** K. Digby *Two Treat.* ɪ. ii. 14
>    There remaineth no more to be said of this subiect, but to enumerate the seuerall specieses of Quantity.
> - **1792** Ld. Monboddo *Orig. & Progress of Lang.* ix. 110
>    These perfect ideas of Plato are no other than the specieses of things which were held by Aristotle to exist in the mind of the deity.

Thus *species* is not the same word as *specie*, and never has been so outside of a few scattered obsolete or erroneous uses.

## Visits “received *in specie*, paid *in individuo*”

The distinct word *specie* meaning a coin or coined money is used almost
exclusively in the Latin phrase *in specie* for “in kind” where it takes
the ablative grammatical case inflection. The phrase was often set in
italic to indicate this.

> - **1551** T. Cranmer *Answer S. Gardiner* 182
>    As vnto the Jewes Christe was geuen in figures, so to vs he is gyven *in specie*, that is to say, *in rei veritate*, in his very nature.
> - **1562** W. Turner 2nd Pt. Herball f. 93ᵛ
>    Pitiusa is iudged to differ in spicie or kynde from the cypresse spourge.
> - **1620** H. Wotton Dispatch from Vienna 7 Sept. in Reliquiæ Wottonianæ (1685) 501
>    Whether visits of respect..being received *in specie*, should be paid *in individuo*.
> - **a1637** B. Jonson Timber 2714 in Wks. (1640) III
>    They differ; but *in specie*: either in the kinde is absolute.

For the freestanding, non-Latin use, we see:

> - **1671** in *9th Rep. Royal Comm. Hist. MSS* (1883) App. II. 13/2
>    Unpurged brown [sugar], being the specie of the country [Barbadoes], pays for the exports from the kingdom.
> - **1710** *True Acct. Last Distemper T. Whigg* ɪɪ. 19
>    A Bung-Cart [*perh. read* Dung-Cart], drawn by an Ox and an Ass, and laden with Specie and Exchequer Bills, to purchase Country Votes.
> - **1749**   T. Smollett tr. A. R. Le Sage *Gil Blas* IV. x. x. 67  
>    I sometimes kissed the species, and contemplated the different pieces with..rapture.
> - **1864** F. C. Bowen *Treat. Logic* ix. 274
>    Money may mean either specie, or bank-notes, or currency consisting of a mixture of these two.

## Summary

So singular *species* did at no point ever “take over” from some singular *specie*. It has always been there.